# Rails Low-level Caching Google Translate API Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

I am trying to do a simple low-level cache of the google translate API in my rails application, but caching is not working correctly:

1) If `cache_key = ['google_translate', 'first']`, translatedcontent is '第一' and is correct.

2) If `cache_key = ['google_translate', 'second']`, translatedcontent is '第二' which is correct.

3) If `cache_key = ['google_translate', 'first']` again, translatedcontent is (empty) when I should be expecting '第一'

I can confirm that the API was called during the first two queries, and was not called (as expected) on the third query albeit being incorrect.

---

Here is my code:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord

  def self.query_model(model_uid, text)
    cache_key = [model_uid, text]
    translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new
    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
      translatedcontent = translate.translate text, from: 'en', to: "zh-cn"        
    end
    return translatedcontent
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it seems so obvious but it seems like most rails caching tutorials/examples don't show caching being used this way.

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord

  def self.query_model(model_uid, text)
    cache_key = [model_uid, text]
    translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new
    translatedcontent = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
      translatedcontent = translate.translate text, from: 'en', to: "zh-cn"        
    end
    return translatedcontent
  end

end
```